# CSS3 - Rotate Clockwise than Counter Clockwise

Tags: css

I have an HTML element defined like this:

```
<div id="myElement" class="rotated">&gt;</div>
<button onClick="toggle('myElement');">Toggle</button>

function toggle(eid) {
  var el = document.getElementById(eid);
  if (el) {
    el.className += el.className ? 'rotate-clockwise' : 'rotate-counter-clockwise';
  }
}
```

I then have my CSS defined like this:

```
.rotated {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

@keyframes rotateClockwise { from { ? } to { ? } }
.rotate-clockwise {
  animation rotateClockwise 0.1s linear;
}

@keyframes rotateCounterClockwise { from { ? } to { ? } }
.rotate-counter-clockwise {
  animation rotateCounterClockwise 0.1s linear;
}
```

I'm not sure what to add for the `from` and `to` values of my `keyframes`. The fact that my element starts rotated by 90 degrees kind of throws me off. Am I on the correct track or way off?

Thanks!

Comment: When you say rotate clockwise and rotate counter clockwise, is it a rotate from its base position or from its current position. That is, lets assume you want the element to be rotated by xdeg in either direction. When I first click the button it goes to say 90+x deg and when I click it again should it come to 90deg or 90-x deg?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your element starts rotated because it has the `.rotated` class, which tells it to be rotated by `90deg`.

I modified your example a little to make it more idiomatic.

```js
var button = document.querySelector('button')
var el = document.querySelector('#myElement')

function toggle(event) {
  el.classList.toggle('rotate-clockwise')
}

button.addEventListener('click', toggle, false)
```

```css
.my-element {
  display: inline-block;
  transition: transform 0.1s linear;
}

.rotate-clockwise {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="myElement" class="my-element">&gt;</div>
<button>Toggle</button>
```

In the javascript we first get our button and element so we can operate on it later (we use `querySelector` which is more modern and lets you use CSS selectors). Then we define your event handler, which simply toggles the `rotate-clockwise` CSS class on and off. Lastly we attach our `toggle` function as a click event handler to the button.

In CSS we tell `my-element` to be `inline-block` as to not stretch over the entire width of the window. Also, every change to `transform` should use a linear transition of 0.1s. Every time `.rotate-clockwise` gets added or removed the element rotates.

Hopefully this does what you want and helps you understand the problem better.